# Can I use a mixed model even when my independent variables are all fixed effects?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-estimating-equations, longitudinal-data-analysis

I need to use longitudinal data for my model. Two possible options to deal with the lack of independence between observations: GEE and Mixed models. But, how Mixed model can even be an option if all my potential explanatory variables are fixed effects?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use a mixed-effect model then you specify that the subject ID (i.e. a code which is a unique identifier for each subject that was repeatedly measured) is a random effect. [Here](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/workshops/mixed/NormalWithR.pdf) is a link covering how to do this in R.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter that all the explanatory variables are fixed effects. Assuming that you have repeated measurements for subjects then you would just specify the subject ID variable as a grouping variable, which will fit random intercepts in the mixed model framework. You could also specify random slopes for the fixed effects, if warranted.

However before simply throwing all possible explanatory variables into a model, it is a good idea to give some thought to the causal process involved, so as not to include mediators in the model, as this may [invoke a reversal paradox](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18211676).